# What do these strange headers mean and what is this hacker trying to do?

Tags: nginx

I've recently deployed a public website and looking at the nginx access logs I see hackers trying to access different php admin pages (which is fine, I don't use php), but I also see requests like this:

```
85.239.221.75 - - [27/Dec/2019:14:52:42 +0000] "k\xF7\xE9Y\xD3\x06)\xCF\xA92N\xC7&\xC4Oq\x93\xDF#\xBF\x88:\xA9\x97\xC0N\xAC\xFE>)9>\x0Cs\xC1\x96RB,\xE1\xE2\x16\xB9\xD1_Z-H\x16\x08\xC8\xAA\xAF?\xFB4\x91%\xD9\xDD\x15\x16\x8E\xAB\xF5\xA6'!\xF8\xBB\xFBBx\x85\xD9\x8E\xC9\x22\x176\xF0E\x8A\xCDO\xD1\x1EnW\xEB\xA3D|.\xAC\x1FB\xC9\xFD\x89a\x88\x93m\x11\xEB\xE7\xA9\xC0\xC3T\xC5\xAEF\xF7\x8F\x9E\xF7j\x03l\x96\x92t c\xE4\xB5\x10\x1EqV\x0C5\xF8=\xEE\xA2n\x98\xB4" 400 182 "-" "-"
```

What is this hacker sending and what are they trying to do? And what should I do to stay ahead of this type of attack?

Answer (score 0):

The data you are having is hex formatted. It is more likely showed because of making HTTPS request to an HTTP request endpoint. Because HTTP expects plain text data and you are giving it HTTPS data which is encrypted, that's why you are seeing bunch of gibberish regarding that log.